# Common Emitter Colpitts oscillator

Tags: transistors, rf, bjt, oscillator, feedback

Good day, we were tasked to design a transistor based RF oscillator to be used as a VCO for our design experiment. In the picture shown below I have seen many tutorials on how to set the L1, C2, C3 values. I also already know how to set R1 and R2 as they are only used to bias the transistor. I would just like to ask

> What are the C1 and C5 capacitors, and the L2 inductor for and how do I set them to a certain value?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C5 is relatively large, it decouples the emitter to keep the AC gain high.

L2,C2,C3 form a parallel resonant circuit. L1 is simply an RF choke (high impedance at oscillator frequency).

C1 can be relatively small as it provides positive feedback to the transistor's base which is a relatively high impedance node - its actual value will depend on Cbe and (Ccb * voltage gain) - the latter being the Miller capacitance. These (Cbe and Miller capacitance) are effectively in parallel, and will attenuate the base signal.

C1 will also depend on the ratio of C2 to C3 which provide the ground tap on the resonant circuit: if C2 > C3 then X(C2) < X(C3) and the tap is closer to L1, reducing the positive feedback voltage via C1.

Comment: How can C1 provide  "positive feedback to the transistor`s base"?

Comment: @LvW : Because the C2/C3 tap is grounded, the voltage above C2 is out of phase with the collector thus in phase with the base voltage.

Comment: ....in phase with the base voltage? But the base voltage is inverse (180deg) with respect to the collector! With other words: What is wrong (in your view) with my explanation?

Comment: Exactly. The base voltage is 180 degrees out of phase with the collector. Now look at the tuned circuit - C2,C3 and L2 (not L1). Imagine there was a tap somewhere on L2, and that tap was grounded. What would that imply about the phase of the voltage at the top of L2? It is 180 degrees out of phase with the collector and in phase with the base. (The grounded tap is actually between C2 and C3).

Comment: Brian D, perhaps I misunderstood your description. But that`s not the point. The point is the following: The L2-C2-C3 combination is - without any doubt - a third order lowpass. Driven with a non-ideal current source (BJT with internal resistance ro) we get the classical 3rd-oder lowpass function between the collector node and the common node of C2 and C1. And this lowpass has a phase shift of -180 deg at wo=1/SQRT(LC) with C=C2||C3. I admit, this formula LOOKS like a bandpass resonant frequency. But it is not! It is a 3rd-order lowpass.

Comment: Sure, topologically it resembles a lowpass (excluding L1) -  that doesn't contradict anything I said. It is also a parallel resonant circuit and that - given it is designed for high Q - is its dominant characteristic. If it were a practical lowpass it would be fed from - or work into - lower impedances or incorporate a damping element into the tuned circuit, or possibly all three, to control the Q.  But that would be counter to its purpose as an oscillator. So I'm sorry but I don't see the point you want to make, and to say "we have no resonant circuit" is at least doubtful.

Comment: My point is the following: For designing/analyzing the circuit I need the loop gain transfer function. And this loop gain function contains - as the frequency-determining brach - a 3rd-order lowpass. Thats all. No need to introduce a parallel resonant circuit. From my experience, I know that this fact (lowpass vs. parallel resonant circuit) sometimes confuses students because they do not know how to explain the working principle of this circuit (bandpass or lowpass?). That`s the only reason for my objections against the term "parallel resonant circuit". Do you understand now?

Comment: I agree the low pass filter view allows a different approach to the same solution. Which approach is easier to understand probably depend on the student.

Comment: Hi Brian - I think, we are close together. Indeed, two different approaches are possible - please, see my EDIT2. I must admit - interesting discussion with some new insights on my side. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation/explanation is a bit different from Brian Drummond`s description. For my opinion, we have no "resonant circuit" (L1, C2, C3) because this would not explain why we have positive feedback. The common node between C2 and C3 is grounded - and therefore, the working principle is as follows:

- The feedback path resembles a **third-order lowpass** which can produce a phase shift of -180deg at the common node between L2 and C2 for the desired oscillation frequency. Together with the inverting characteristic of a common-emitter stage (between B and C) we have a total phase shift of -360 deg (positive feedback) .
- **Lowpass**: It is a simple task to see that the lowpass function is realized as a classical 4-element ladder circuit: ro-C3 (grounded), L2-C2 (grounded). The resistance ro is the dynamic output resistance of the transistor.
- The task of C1 is to couple the feedback signal to the base node and L1 decouples the feedback node from Vcc - otherwise we would have no feedback at all. The capacitor C5 cancels the negative feedback effect of R3 for the oscillation frequency (and, thus, allows a larger gain).

**EDIT1:**
Keeping in mind that neither L1 nor C1 (should) contribute to the feedback path the lowpass function between output (collector) and the upper end of C2 can be derived. For this purpose, the transistor is  assumed to be a current source I with an internal dynamic resistance ro:

**H(s)=Vout/I=ro/[1 + s*(C2+C3)*ro + s²*L2*C2 + s³*C2*C3*L2*ro)**

It can be shown that this lowpass has an amplitude peak with a phase shift of exactly -180deg for **w=1/SQRT(L2*Cp)** with Cp=C2C3/(C2+C3).

**EDIT2:** With respect to Brian Drummond`s last comment - I agree that two alternative methods exist to explain the working principle of the circuit - however, finally both approaches join in a common loop gain function. Let me explain:

In my detailed answer I have, from the beginning and based on a visual inspection, the feedback path treated as a 3rd-order lowpass. This can explain why such a network produces a 180deg phase shift at one single frequency.

However, **another view** is possible - as proposed by Brian Drummond: The collector path contains a parallel LC tank circuit. It is well-known that at the resonant frequency wo=1/SQRT(LC) the voltage across the tank circuit assumes a maximum and the CURRENT through each of the parallel branches also is at its maximum value. If we treat the transistor as anon-ideal current source (internal resistance ro) the current through the capacitive branch is

**Ic=I*[sro*C2/D(s)]** with denominator D(s) as given in the function H(s) above (EDIT1). This current resembles a bandpass function.

The signal which is fed back to the base node is the voltage V2 across C2. This voltage is nothing else than **V2=Ic*(1/sC2)** . Therefore, we arrive again at the lowpass function H(s).

**Summary**: The tank circuit contains a current function which has a bandpass character. Using the voltage across a capacitor as a feedback signal we divide the current function by sC2 and arrive at a lowpass function with a peak and a phase shift of -180deg at w=wo. This is the way to explain the relation between bandpass and lowpass functions (and the role of the resonant frequency wo) in the shown circuit.